# Empty Lines at End of TSV file Creating Empty Column in MySQL Load Data Infile

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-mws

What's the best way to amend this issue, in either MySQL or PHP?

I'm using the Amazon PHP SDK, GetReport function.

```
$intry  = (stream_get_contents($request->getReport()) . "\n");
$merchantalldata = '_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_ALL_DATA_' . $today0 . '.tsv';
file_put_contents($merchantalldata,$intry);

$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_ALL_DATA_" . $today00 . ".tsv' INTO TABLE . . . . "
```

Always on my returned TSV, it's always the same:

[image]
[image]

How can I fix this issue, whether in the TSV file itself, via PHP, or disallow this blank entry from being inserted in the MySQL database?

Comment: Remove the `"\n"`???  And trim if needed `$intry  = trim(stream_get_contents($request->getReport()));`

Comment: Oh wow. Missing the obvious! the `\n` was in the sample/example and I didn't even give it a second thought. Removed that it and the issue was resolved! Thanks so much.. you saved me a lot of time :)

Comment: Would you like to make a reply so I can mark as resolved or should I just delete it? Up to you :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `"\n"` in the `stream_get_contents()` call, then `trim()` if needed:

```
$intry = trim(stream_get_contents($request->getReport()));
```